# Simple UploadPage azure blob using pageBlobClient

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I am using Premium/Hot, LRS, StorageV2 Azure storage and trying to write a simple string but I keep getting an authentication error.

To generate the SAS URI of the container in the portal, I went to:
storage resource -> containers -> my container -> shared access token -> generate SAS token and URL

```
// SAS URI of blob container
var sasUriStr = "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername?sp=r&st=2021-08-10T00:34:00Z&se=2021-08-15T08:34:00Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=ABCDEFGH/YJKLMNOP=";
var uri = new Uri(sasUriStr);
var pageBlobClient = new PageBlobClient(uri);
pageBlobClient.UploadPages(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello world")), 0);
```

> Unhandled exception. Azure.RequestFailedException: Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
> is formed correctly including the signature.
> Time:2021-08-12T20:22:44.0905117Z Status: 403 (Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
> is formed correctly including the signature.) ErrorCode:
> AuthenticationFailed
>
> Additional Information: AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature did not
> match. String to sign used was r

I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you

UPDATE:

After adding /blob name to SAS URI I get this error:

> ```
> Unhandled exception. Azure.RequestFailedException: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
> RequestId:7a741951-401c-00c9-3ce3-8f5076000000
> Time:2021-08-13T01:38:13.4585107Z
> Status: 400 (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.)
> ErrorCode: InvalidHeaderValue
>
> Additional Information:
> HeaderName: x-ms-range
> HeaderValue: bytes=0-10
>
> Content:
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
> RequestId:7a741951-401c-00c9-3ce3-8f5076000000
> Time:2021-08-13T01:38:13.4585107Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-range</HeaderName><HeaderValue>bytes=0-10</HeaderValue></Error>
>
> Headers:
> Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
> x-ms-error-code: InvalidHeaderValue
> x-ms-request-id: 7a741951-401c-00c9-3ce3-8f5076000000
> x-ms-version: 2020-08-04
> x-ms-client-request-id: 4366d771-7f70-4bbf-9677-6e9fcf3cb7a1
> Date: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 01:38:12 GMT
> Content-Length: 327
> Content-Type: application/xml
> ```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SAS URL you’re using (do obfuscate account name and sig portion of your SAS token). Also share the complete error message.

Comment: I’ll provide a detailed answer shortly but the reason you’re getting this error is because your SAS URL is missing blob name. Just insert blob name between “containername” and “?” and your code should work fine.

Comment: @GauravMantri can you please provide details? e.g. `.../containername_blobname?sp=1...`

Comment: …/containername/blobname?…..

Comment: Please make sure that the blob already exists before you put the page otherwise you’ll get 404 error.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am now getting a different error

Comment: @GauravMantri the file had to be exactly 512 bytes, but why exactly 512 bytes? It works now

Comment: @GauravMantri I asked another PageBlob question, I was wondering if you are familiar with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825470/azure-pageblob-upload-a-new-file-x-ms-blob-content-length-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Please change your code to something like:

```
var sasUriStr = "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername?sp=r&st=2021-08-10T00:34:00Z&se=2021-08-15T08:34:00Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=ABCDEFGH/YJKLMNOP=";
var uri = new Uri(sasUriStr);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(uri);
var pageBlobClient = containerClient.GetPageBlobClientCore("page-blob-name");
pageBlobClient.UploadPages(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello world")), 0);
```

Please ensure that the blob already exists before you use this code.

### Problem

The reason you were running into the problem is because you were trying to create a `PageBlobClient` using a URI representing a blob container SAS. Because of this, Azure Storage service assumed that your blob name is `containername` and the container is [`$root`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/working-with-the-root-container). Since the SAS token was obtained for `containername` blob container and the service used `$root` blob container for validating the SAS token, you are getting authorization failed error.

By creating a [`BlobContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) using the SAS URL and then creating a [`PageBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.pageblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) using [`BlobContainerClient.GetPageBlobClientCore(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getpageblobclientcore?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_GetPageBlobClientCore_System_String_) solves the problem.

Comment: Isn't GetPageBlobClientCore a protected method?