# PageBlob upload as one chunk: x-ms-range invalid

Tags: python, azure, blob

This is a follow up question to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825470/azure-pageblob-upload-a-new-file-x-ms-blob-content-length-error), I am now trying to use [PutPage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-page) to upload the file as one chunk. The first part that reserves a space works. I get an error in the second API call saying something is wrong with `x-ms-range` value

```
import os
import http.client
from urllib.parse import urlparse

sas_uri = '<SAS URI>'
uri = urlparse(sas_uri)

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(uri.hostname, port=uri.port, timeout=3000)

file_path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\npp.Installer.exe"

with open(file_path, 'rb') as reader:
    file = reader.read()

    file_size = os.stat(file_path).st_size
    block_size = file_size
    boundary = block_size % 512
    if boundary != 0:
        block_size = block_size + 512 - boundary

    # Reserve a block space
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'PageBlob',
        'x-ms-blob-content-length': block_size
    }
    
    conn.request('PUT', sas_uri, '', headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

    # Upload the file
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': file_size,
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'PageBlob',
        'x-ms-page-write': 'update',
        'x-ms-range': f'bytes=0-{file_size-1}'
    }
    conn.request('PUT', sas_uri + '&comp=page', file, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Error:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
> RequestId:c3c776d3-e01c-00b7-80de-9386a5000000
> Time:2021-08-18T03:11:14.5181971Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-range</HeaderName><HeaderValue>bytes=0-3991191</HeaderValue></Error>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is failing is because the data you're uploading is not aligned with the 512 bytes boundary. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-page#remarks):

> Each range of pages submitted with Put Page for an update operation
> may be up to 4 MiB in size. **The start and end range of the page must
> be aligned with 512-byte boundaries**. If you attempt to upload a range
> of pages that is larger than 4MB, the service returns status code 413
> (Request Entity Too Large).

Please try the following code:

```
import sys
import os
import http.client
from urllib.parse import urlparse

sas_uri = '<SAS URI here>'
uri = urlparse(sas_uri)
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(uri.hostname, port=uri.port, timeout=3000)

file_path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\npp.Installer.exe"
with open(file_path, 'rb') as reader:
    file = reader.read()
    file_size = os.stat(file_path).st_size
    block_size = file_size
    boundary = block_size % 512
    if boundary != 0:
        padarray = b'\0' * (512 - boundary)
        file = file + padarray
        block_size = block_size + 512 - boundary
    # Reserve a block space
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'PageBlob',
        'x-ms-blob-content-length': block_size
    }
    conn.request('PUT', sas_uri, '', headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

    # Upload the file
    headers = {
        'Content-Length': block_size,
        'x-ms-page-write': 'update',
        'Range': f'bytes=0-{block_size-1}'
    }
    conn.request('PUT', sas_uri + '&comp=page', file, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I asked this question, its a similar question but in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999851/non-hacky-way-to-upload-file-to-pageblob-using-azure-sdk