# PageBlob upload as multiple chunks: x-ms-range invalid

Tags: python, azure, blob

This is a follow-up question to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826122/pageblob-upload-as-one-chunk-x-ms-range-invalid). What I realized is I can only upload [4 mega bytes max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/request-body-large) to Azure. So I was trying to modify the code to chunk upload to pageblob. But now I get an error trying to upload the first chunk.

```
sas_uri = '<SAS URI>'
uri = urlparse(sas_uri)

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(uri.hostname, port=uri.port, timeout=3000)

file_path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\npp.Installer.exe"

def chunk(msg, n):
    for i in range(0, len(msg), n):
        yield msg[i:i + n]


with open(file_path, 'rb') as reader:
    file = reader.read()

    file_size = len(file)
    block_size = file_size
    boundary = block_size % 512
    if boundary != 0:
        padding = b'\0' * (512 - boundary)
        file = file + padding
        block_size = block_size + 512 - boundary    # needed to make the file on boundary

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'PageBlob',
        'x-ms-blob-content-length': block_size
    }

    # Reserve a block space
    conn.request('PUT', sas_uri, '', headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

    CHUNK_MAX_SIZE = int(4e+6) # 4 mega bytes
    index = 0
    for chunk in chunk(file, CHUNK_MAX_SIZE):
        chunk_size = len(chunk)
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Length': chunk_size,
            'x-ms-blob-type': 'PageBlob',
            'x-ms-page-write': 'update',
            'x-ms-range': f"bytes={index}-{index + chunk_size - 1}"
        }
        # Upload the file
        conn.request('PUT', sas_uri + '&comp=page', file, headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))

        index = index + chunk_size
```

Error:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
> RequestId:c312a91d-401c-0000-44e9-95bd08000000
> Time:2021-08-21T17:33:47.2909476Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-range</HeaderName><HeaderValue>bytes=0-3999999</HeaderValue></Error>
> ```

Update: I corrected the `CHUNK_MAX_SIZE` so now the first chunk gets uploaded without error but subsequent chunks result in this error:

> !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML
> 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">Bad
> Request\r\n
>
> ### Bad Request - Invalid
> Verb
>
> ---
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request verb is
> invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line of code:

```
CHUNK_MAX_SIZE = int(4e+6) # 4 mega bytes
```

It gives you `4000000` which is not 4MB. 4MB is `4194304` bytes.

Please try by changing your code to:

```
CHUNK_MAX_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024 # or 4194304
```

and your code should work fine.

**UPDATE**

Please change the following line of code:

```
conn.request('PUT', sas_uri + '&comp=page', file, headers)
```

to

```
conn.request('PUT', sas_uri + '&comp=page', chunk, headers)
```

and you should be able to upload the file. Essentially I changed `file` to `chunk` in your code as you would want to just upload the chunk and not the entire file.

Comment: WOW. How did you figure it out?

Comment: `print(CHUNK_MAX_SIZE)` and `print(headers)` are your best friends :D.

Comment: I have an unrelated question, do you know how to find out if SAS URI is a block blob or page blob? because we can do a head request and in response header `x-ms-blob-type` which should say blockblob or pageblob. But if the file doesn't exist then we get 404 not found and then we need to upload a blob by trying pageblob and if it fails we know its a block blob. I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: SAS URI is blob type agnostic. You can use the same SAS URI to upload any kind of blob (block, page or append). I am not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Would you mind elaborating that? May be ask another question?

Comment: I asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869915/find-the-type-of-azure-storage-using-sas-uri-of-blob

Comment: the first chunk uploads successfully but subsequent chunks fail. I updated the question. Sorry I keep asking questions.

Comment: No worries . Let me take a look shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very thankful. Thank you

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: That was my mistake. I am sorry