# Find the type of azure storage using SAS URI of blob

Tags: azure, rest, blob

I was wondering how to tell if the [type of azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-pageblob-overview?tabs=dotnet) based on SAS URI of blob? or more specifically how to know if it is PageBlob or BlockBlob.

There is a [REST API that returns a type of blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties) by just doing a HEAD request to SAS URI and if the file exists there is a field in the response header `x-ms-blob-type` which indicates the type of blob. However, if the file doesn't exist it returns 404. Now when we get a 404 we can upload a dummy file using BlockBlob and if it fails then we know it's a PageBlob. But I am wondering is there a better way? more straightforward way.

Example of SAS URI:

```
var sasUriStr = "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/file?sp=r&st=2021-08-10T00:34:00Z&se=2021-08-15T08:34:00Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=ABCDEFGH/YJKLMNOP=";
```

Comment: My guess is that you want to find out what kind of blob types (block, page, append) are supported by a storage account. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That's it. However, I don't want to assume for example if it's Premium LRS then it has to support PageBlob. I want to know what it supports based on a SAS URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to find that information however it requires you to bring in your logic and it requires a different kind of SAS token.

What you have to do is create an [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) (currently you're using Service SAS) and then invoke [`Get Account Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-account-information) REST API using that token. Next you will need to extract `x-ms-sku-name` and `x-ms-account-kind` response headers.  Based on the values of these, you will have to come up with a logic for supported blob types. For example,

- If the value of `x-ms-account-kind` is `BlobStorage`, then it only supports `Block Blobs` and `Append Blobs`.
- If the value of `x-ms-account-kind` is not `BlobStorage` or `BlockBlobStorage` and value of `x-ms-sku-name` is `PremiumLRS`, then it only supports `Page Blobs`.

I wrote a blog post some time ago where I created a matrix of features supported by account kinds and skus. You can read that blog post here: https://www.ais.com/how-to-choose-the-right-kind-of-azure-storage-account/

From this blog post:

[image]

Comment: I have a question, Please correct me if I am wrong. Is downloading of PageBlob and BlockBlob the same and write operation is different? I assumed downloading are the same because if we have a blob URI we can just use a GET to download the blob.

Comment: Lastly, is there a documentation that supports my hypothesis of downloading the blob is the same for both of them regardless of type of blob. Maybe this should be a separate question ...

Comment: Downloading blob is the same however page blobs download can be optimized (sparse download) and that makes the download different. Please ask a separate question.

Comment: Asked as a separate question. Thank you so much as always https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69128675/downloading-of-blob-in-pageblob-vs-blockblob

Comment: how to translate this table into a code? do you have it as a CSV?