# How to get blob properties from resource ID

Tags: c#, blob, azure-sdk

I am wondering given ARM ID or resource ID of blob, how to get blob properties such as `primaryEndpoints`

Example resource ID:

```
/subscriptions/abffff89-2c76-424a-af4c-34b2512a3cb4/resourceGroups/foo-bar-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/foobar
```

There is a get blob properties REST API, I am wondering is there an equivalent in C# azure-sdk?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/get-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Azure SDK`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/storage/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage) for that. The packages you would want to install are `Azure.ResourceManager.Storage` and `Azure.Identity`.

Here's the code to get the information about a storage account based on the resource id:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage;

namespace SO69264616
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var resourceId = "/subscriptions/abffff89-2c76-424a-af4c-34b2512a3cb4/resourceGroups/foo-bar-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/foobar";
            var resourceElements = resourceId.Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var subscriptionId = resourceElements[1];
            var resourceGroupName = resourceElements[3];
            var storageAccountName = resourceElements[resourceElements.Length - 1];
            var credentials = new AzureCliCredential();
            var armClient = new ArmClient(credentials);
            Subscription subscription = armClient.GetSubscription($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}");
            ResourceGroup resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync(resourceGroupName);
            StorageAccountContainer storageAccountContainer = resourceGroup.GetStorageAccounts();
            StorageAccount storageAccount = await storageAccountContainer.GetAsync(storageAccountName);
            Console.WriteLine(storageAccount.Data.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `AzureCliCredential` because for some reason `DefaultAzureCredential` did not work for me. You should try with `DefaultAzureCredential` first.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering can you please help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614065/set-debug-level-when-deploying-using-azure-arm-template-with-c-sharp