# set debug level when deploying using Azure ARM template with C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

How to set debug level when deploying using Azure ARM template with C#

```cs
var deployment = azure.Deployments.Define(parameters.DeploymentName)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(parameters.ResourceGroupName)
    .WithTemplate(vmTemplate)
    .WithParameters(deploymentParameters)
    .WithMode(DeploymentMode.Complete)
    .Create();
```

In Powershell, there is an option we can use:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -deploymentdebuglevel
```

[source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/debugging-arm-template-deployments/)

Comment: As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.deployment.definition?view=azure-dotnet) documentation, We don't have any way of passing `debug` when deploying arm template with C#

Comment: check debugSettings class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.models.debugsetting?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by [mtz1406](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626139/mtz1406) you can try checking the below debug setting class in ARM template.

```
public class DebugSetting
```

Inherite the object as debug

Here is the Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.models.debugsetting?view=azure-dotnet) for Debug class setting.