# Upload PageBlob To Azure Storage Using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload a file with `BlobType="PageBlob"` to Azure Storage using Java.
On command line, I am able to do it by simply specifying `--blob-type PageBlob` argument to `azcopy` command. In Java, I have:

```
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("test.bmp");
blobClient.uploadFromFile("data/test.bmp");
```

However, it uploads a file with `BlockBlob` type.

I am aware of [getPageBlobClient()](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.25.1/com/azure/storage/blob/BlobClient.html#getPageBlobClient()) method but it does not offer an `uploadFromFile()` method that takes file path as an argument as shown above. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware of [getPageBlobClient()](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.25.1/com/azure/storage/blob/BlobClient.html#getPageBlobClient()) method, but it does not offer an `uploadFromFile()` method that takes a file path as an argument, as shown above. How can I do it? Thanks.

As of now, there is no direct command to upload a **`page blob`** using the Azure Java SDK.

According to this **[MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-pageblob-overview)**:

Page blobs are a type of data storage in Azure that are designed for storing index-based and sparse data structures like **`OS`** and data disks for **`Virtual Machines`** and **`Databases`**. Page blobs are made up of 512-byte pages, which can be read and written to individually, making them ideal for storing data structures that require random access. For example, Azure SQL DB uses page blobs to store its databases. Additionally, page blobs are often used for files that require range-based updates.

You can use the **[Put page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-page?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)** REST API request, which is used to create a page blob and write the blob aligned with a 512-byte boundary.

**Request:**

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=page
```

You can refer to this **[SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826122/pageblob-upload-as-one-chunk-x-ms-range-invalid)** by Gaurav Mantri for uploading a page blob using Python code.